# Thymeleaf: How to fix updating @ManyToMany table

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, thymeleaf

I have created a form using thymeleaf for updating books information.
Authors and Book have a @ManyToMany relationship. The problem is that when I save my changes, the @ManytoMany table (Book_Authors) row is deleted.

> I am not trying to change the values of authors for the edited book, I simply want to
>   preserve the old ones.
>
> I have tried saving each author ID in a 'input type = "hidden" ' since
>   this worked for saving values for @OneToMany relationship like
>   'PUBLISHER'

This works (Publisher old value is saved in database):

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Publisher:</label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
   <input type="hidden" th:field="*{publisher.id}" />
   <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" th:field=" 
                                 {publisher.name}">
  </div>
 </div>
```

This doesn't work:

```
<div th:each = "author : ${authors}">
       <input type="hidden" th:field="*{author.id}" /> 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<tr th:each="vehicle, itemStat : ${form.vehicles}">
    <td>
        <input hidden th:name="|vehicles[${itemStat.index}].id|" th:value="${vehicle.getId()}"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input th:name="|vehicles[${itemStat.index}].brand|" th:value="${vehicle.getBrand()}"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input th:name="|vehicles[${itemStat.index}].price|" th:value="${vehicle.getPrice()}"/>
    </td>
</tr>`

further reading : -

1. https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-list
2. http://forum.thymeleaf.org/I-have-problem-in-binding-the-list-of-objects-contained-inside-a-object-on-the-form-using-thymeleaf-td3525038.html

and also u have to change cascadeType.ALL 
if use @OneToMany use orphanRemoval=true